# OpenSSH key authentication only possible if password access is enabled

Tags: ubuntu, ssh-keys

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 0 as a headless server.
I have setup key authentication to access the server through Putty. I used Putty keygen to generate a 4096 bit key, popped that onto the server and am able to authenticate successfully UNTIL I disable password access in `sshd_config` then I get the *"Server refused our key"* message from Putty when trying to authenticate.
Just changed the following in `sshd_config` (this is a fresh Ubuntu install):

```
PermitRootLogin no
PasswordAuthentication no
UsePAM no
```

Comment: You should check the server logs: `/var/log/auth.log`. I would hazard a guess that it's either a perms issue on the ssh directory on the server or the ownership perms on your private key client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rechecked the Ubuntu permissions and they appeared to be correct. However I decided to reapply them and chmod'd the same level permissions to the /.ssh directory at 0700 and 0644 to the authorized keys file and that seems to work. Baffling as these were the existing permission levels anyway.....